# Deleted a Windows folder using Linux command rmdir -rf foldername

Tags: windows-7, linux, bash, git

I have a folder on a Windows 7 machine with contents in it and decided to delete it using Git Bash, namely with the command `rmdir -rf foldername`.

According to this manual http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000798.htm

The result: `the contents have been deleted and the empty folder remains.` I've tried to delete it using a number of different methods but to no avail. Getting accessibility errors.

NB: The Windows is a virtual

Comment: Windows is in a VM? Can you use windows tools, like a file explorer or command prompt to delete the folders?

Comment: No that didn't work either. It was saying no access rights. Restarting the Virtual MAchine resolved the issue. Possibly I forgot to refresh the window. Not sure and no time to look into it..

Comment: What are the accessibility error messages? Are they something along the lines of `Access Denied`? If so have you tried opening the Git bash as administrator?